# Control relay using split core current transformer

Tags: relay, current-measurement

I have a YHDC SCT013-03 split core current transform which lists an output range from 0 V to 1 V for an input up to 30 A. My objective is to use this to open an close a contact switch.

The way I was thinking this could be achieved was to attach both the transformer and the contact switch to a relay. The transformer could open/close the relay causing the contact switch to open/close.

If I understand what I read correctly we get AC out of the transformer with a range from -1 V to 1 V. All the relays I have used in the past are controlled by DC.  Should I be looking for an AC relay? It is not know at this time at what voltage we need the relay to open, and ideally we could somehow have an adjustable set point. I was also really hoping the thing could be self powered.

Any suggestions an the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely unlikely that you can use the output of that device to directly operate any kind of relay. The output needs to go to some kind of signal amplifier. The output is likely 1 volt AC RMS, not 1 V peak or +/- 1 V.

Comment: Is there an alternative device I should look into or is that a general statement that applies to all split core current transformers?

Comment: In general, a signal output from a sensor is not going to be suitable to power much of anything except that some items that provide a 4 to 20 mA DC signal might be able to power something. There may be some non-split type current transformers that have external load resistor specifications that would permit powering some circuitry and a relay. Where I used to work, someone designed a current transformer to allow something unusual to be done with the output.